# How to properly align nested grid with split gutters

Tags: susy-sass

Is is possible to have nested grids, with split gutters, aligned with the ancestor grid columns?

This is easily done with the before or after positioned gutters, with the `first` and `last` attributes but im achieving a similar result with split gutters. Not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Eric Suzanne, it can be done like this:

Use the nest keyword to tell Susy that a span has children. This is only needed with inside and split gutters — which you are using.

`@include span(first 6 of 12 nest);`